# Number of Occurrences in Python

Tags: python, list

```
list1=[ ]
number=int(input("Please enter the number of middle names: "))
print("Please enter the middle names: ")
def count_contain_e():
    for i in range(number):
        data=str(input())
        list1.append(data)
        print list1
        print(list1.count('e'))
count_contain_e()

string2= 'daniels'
print(string2.count('e'))
```

So as you can see, I've made a list (list1) compiling all the middle names. My problem is, when I enter a middle name with the letter 'e' in it (like Daniels), it returns '0'. I'm not sure why. To make sure that the .count part works, I added a little part at the end where I create string2 and enter 'daniels' and then it works. Why does isn't it work in the function part?

Comment: What **language** are you trying to do this in? It looks like Python.

Comment: Why are you calling `int` on an input that's supposed to be a name? If I'm Steve Stevey McSteveson, what kind of integer is "Stevey" supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to count number of occurrences of a specified letter:

```
>>> 'Darlene'.count('e')
2
```

Here's how to do it for a list of names:

```
counts = [x.count('e') for x in names]
```

Here's how to input a list of names:

```
names = []
for i in range(n_of_names):
    names.append(input())
```

Comment: Ok so I changed it using " counts = [x.count('e') for x in names] " but now it comes up with a new problem which didn't occur before. It says that when I type list1.append(data), "UnboundLocalError: local variable list1 referenced before assignment"

Comment: Did you forget to write `list1 = []` at the top? Also, you really should give it a better name than `list1`.

Comment: `counts = [x.count('e') for x in list1]`

Comment: okay so it works now, however, it gives me the occurrences in a list. It says [0, 1] after I input 2 middle names (one with no 'e', and one with one 'e'). I want it just to say the number of occurrences in total.

Comment: Try `sum(counts)`.

Comment: thanks. i really appreciate the help. it finally works!!

Answer (score -1):

```
    data=str(input())
    list1.append(data)
    # list1 = ['daniel']
    print list1
    print(list1.count('e'))
    # 'daniel' != 'e' ... count == 0
```